# Cannot create an array of LinkedLists in Java...?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm working on a sparse matrix class that **needs** to use an array of `LinkedList` to store the values of a matrix. Each element of the array (i.e. each `LinkedList`) represents a row of the matrix. And, each element in the `LinkedList` array represents a column and the stored value.

In my class, I have a declaration of the array as:

```
private LinkedList<IntegerNode>[] myMatrix;
```

And, in my constructor for the `SparseMatrix`, I try to define:

```
myMatrix = new LinkedList<IntegerNode>[numRows];
```

The error I end up getting is

> Cannot create a generic array of `LinkedList<IntegerNode>`.

So, I have two issues with this:

1. What am I doing wrong, and
2. Why is the type acceptable in the declaration for the array if it can't be created?

`IntegerNode` is a class that I have created. And, all of my class files are packaged together.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can't use generic array creation. It's a flaw/ feature of java generics.

The ways without warnings are:

1. Using List of Lists instead of Array of Lists:

   ```
   List< List<IntegerNode>> nodeLists = new LinkedList< List< IntegerNode >>();
   ```
2. Declaring the special class for Array of Lists:

   ```
   class IntegerNodeList {
       private final List< IntegerNode > nodes;
   }
   ```

Comment: A better alternative to the latter solution would be to:

`class IntegerNodeList extends List<IntegerNode> {}`

Comment: This implementation is outrageously slow. Getting the [1000][2000] element (nodeLists.get(1000).get(2000)) will make LinkedList iterate 3000 times! Avoid LinkedList if anyone may be indexing into it.  ArrayList will index faster, but Fredrik's solution is better overall.

Answer (score 145):

For some reason you have to cast the type and make the declaration like this:

```
myMatrix = (LinkedList<IntegerNode>[]) new LinkedList<?>[numRows];
```

Comment: I researched a similar problem and read that the above cast is a very common 'hack' that is used all over the collections framework.

Comment: IMO, this should be the selected answer. I haven't experimented, but I have the gut feeling that Sergey's #2 method creates quite a bit of overhead; and I'm POSITIVE that #1 does. A list is not as efficient as an array in several ways which I won't detail here, but I HAVE done experiments and seen big slowdowns when using lists compared to arrays. It's faster to just manage your own arrays and reallocate them, than to add stuff to a List.

Comment: @Ricket I agree, taken from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html

Comment: I still get a "Type safety: unchecked cast" warning out of it. Bob's solution looks the cleanest to me.

Comment: @Krige there's nothing you can do about that, because it **is** unchecked, hence the warning. And I wouldn't really say that writing an entirely new class is necessarily the "cleaner" solution; especially if we're talking about overhead.

Comment: In JDK 7 the above gives a rawtypes warning. That can be fixed using the unbounded <?> type, but you still get an unchecked warning (which can be suppressed). e.g. <br> <code>myMatrix = (LinkedList<IntegerNode>[]) new LinkedList<?>[numRows];</code>

Comment: This is the best solution. And I think this is a flaw in Java.

Comment: I think the accepted answer is the best answer but I like your answer.  Too bad Generics and arrays requires such innovation.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the syntax issues, it seems strange to me to use an array and a linked list to represent a matrix. To be able to access arbitrary cells of the matrix, you would probably want an actual array or at least an `ArrayList` to hold the rows, as `LinkedList` must traverse the whole list from the first element to any particular element, an `O(n)` operation, as opposed to the much quicker `O(1)` with `ArrayList` or an actual array.

Since you mentioned this matrix is sparse, though, perhaps a better way to store the data is as a map of maps, where a key in the first map represents a row index, and its value is a row map whose keys are a column index, with the value being your IntegerNode class.  Thus:

```
private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, IntegerNode>> myMatrix = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, IntegerNode>>();

// access a matrix cell:
int rowIdx = 100;
int colIdx = 30;
Map<Integer, IntegerNode> row = myMatrix.get(rowIdx); // if null, create and add to matrix
IntegerNode node = row.get(colIdx); // possibly null
```

If you need to be able to traverse the matrix row by row, you can make the row map type a `TreeMap`, and same for traversing the columns in index order, but if you don't need those cases, `HashMap` is quicker than `TreeMap`. Helper methods to get and set an arbitrary cell, handling unset null values, would be useful, of course.

Answer (score 4):

```
class IntegerNodeList extends LinkedList<IntegerNode> {}

IntegerNodeList[] myMatrix = new IntegerNodeList[numRows];
```

Comment: You missed the generics for LinkedList.

Answer (score 3):

> `myMatrix = (LinkedList<IntegerNode>[]) new LinkedList[numRows];`

casting this way works but still leaves you with a nasty warning:

"Type safety: The expression of type List[] needs unchecked conversion.."

> Declaring a special class for Array of Lists:
>
> `class IntegerNodeList { private final List< IntegerNode > nodes; }`

is a clever idea to avoid the warning. maybe a little bit nicer is to use an interface for it:

```
public interface IntegerNodeList extends List<IntegerNode> {}
```

then

```
List<IntegerNode>[] myMatrix = new IntegerNodeList[numRows];
```

compiles without warnings.

doesn't look too bad, does it?

Comment: IntegerNodeList: what class would you use this with? For instance you could not assign an ArrayList <IntegerNode> to it. You would need to extend ArrayList as well...

Comment: there is no need to use the interface IntegerNodeList outside the initialization of the array:

        List<IntegerNode>[] myMatrix = new IntegerNodeList[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < myMatrix.length; i++) {

            myMatrix[i] = new ArrayList<IntegerNode>();

        }

Comment: `List<IntegerNode>[] myMatrix = new IntegerNodeList[numRows];` This has a subtle but important problem. You can *only* put `IntegerNodeList` in the array. `myMatrix[i] = new ArrayList<IntegerNode>();` will throw `ArrayStoreException`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no generic array creation in Java 1.5 (or 1.6 as far as I can tell). See https://community.oracle.com/message/4829402.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String>[] lst = new List[2];
lst[0] = new LinkedList<String>();
lst[1] = new LinkedList<String>();
```

No any warnings. NetBeans 6.9.1, jdk1.6.0_24

Comment: True no warnings but with Oracle's Java SE 6 Update 32 I get the compiling error "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>". Removing the <String> argument generates another error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedList<String> to List".

Answer (score 0):

If I do the following I get the error message in question

```
LinkedList<Node>[] matrix = new LinkedList<Node>[5];
```

But if I just remove the list type in the declaration it seems to have the desired functionality.

```
LinkedList<Node>[] matrix = new LinkedList[5];
```

Are these two declarations drastically different in a way of which I'm not aware?

**EDIT**

Ah, I think I've run into this issue now.

Iterating over the matrix and initializing the lists in a for-loop seems to work. Though it's not as ideal as some of the other solutions offered up.

```
for(int i=0; i < matrix.length; i++){

    matrix[i] = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an array of List, one alternative is to try:

```
private IntegerNode[] node_array = new IntegerNode[sizeOfYourChoice];
```

Then `node_array[i]` stores the head(first) node of a `ArrayList<IntegerNode>` or `LinkedList<IntegerNode>` (whatever your favourite list implementation).

Under this design, you lose the random access method `list.get(index)`, but then you could still traverse the list starting with the head/fist node store in the type safe array.

This might be an acceptable design choice depending on your use case. For instance, I use this design to represent an adjacency list of graph, in most use cases, it requires traversing the adjacency list anyway for a given vertex instead of random access some vertex in the list.