# array of stacks

Tags: java, eclipse, arrays, generics

Is it possible to create an array of stacks without having to cast the stacks as they come out?
Eclipse gives me a warning about not being able to make a generic array of Stack when I do something like this:

```
Stack<Card>[] cards = new Stack<Card>[52];
```

Comment: if you indent your code snippets with four spaces it'll format correctly

Comment: Similar question with some good answers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java

Comment: I think it's an error and not a warning, since "new Stack<Card>[52]" is not allowed in Java - a bit hidden here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.3

Comment: add annotation @SupressWarnings("Unchecked")
:)

Answer (score 10):

Joshua Bloch does an excellent job of describing this problem in *Effective Java, Second Edition*. [Check out the relevant section on Google Book Search](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=bloch+java+generics+arrays&source=bl&ots=yXGgPkq6U4&sig=BtDKify8aUyUE-I_xXxr76ABFzM&hl=en&ei=ldADSqDyBsqrtgefuOWKBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5).

The advice he offers is to prefer lists to arrays. Your code might then look something like:

```
List<Stack<Card>> cards = new ArrayList<Stack<Card>>();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Stack<Card>[] decks = new Stack[9];       // Declare
Card c = decks[5].pop();                  // This compiles - java 'knows' the type
Integer i = decks[4].pop();               // This will not compile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, though this gives you a compiler "unchecked" warning.

```
Stack<Card>[] cards = (Stack<Card>[]) new Stack[52];
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for remembering me that I hate generics :) To be honest making code ugly only that your stupid IDE does not complain is not a good reason to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like to not have to cast them as they come out. Have to follow a tight spec that doesn't allow them to be casted out.

Comment: @Nobert Hartl: it's not the IDE, it's the Java Language Specification!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use arrays anyway ?

It is a low level programming structure.

Using `List` or `Set` instead (eg `org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList`) if you don't want to bother with innitialization.

Or at least

`Arrays.asList(new Stack[52])` to wrap an array into a list.

I couldnt reproduce jour error anywany .. :( perchaps it's because a different warning/errorlevel set.

Comment: Using an array I can limit the number of stacks within it, as the list is an interface, all implementations of the list are not exactly what I need it for.

Comment: see org.apache.commons.collections.list.FixedSizeList

Answer (score 0):

Well, the array does not need to be a generic because he is always defined as this. Why do you think you have to cast? I think that eclipse is somewhat confused here.

Comment: eclipse is not confused: "...It is a compile-time error if the element type is not a reifiable type..."  see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.3

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with type erasure.  Basically the generic types only exist at compile time and have no presence at run time

Have at look at [this forum post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t368874-why-cant-i-create-a-generic-array.html) for a better explanation.