# Java: How to create an array of Map<String,Object> objects

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot create an array of LinkedLists in Java…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java)

I want to call this method:

```
executeBatch(Map<String,Object>[] batch)
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to create an array of `Map<String,Object>[]`

I get the error "Can create a generic array of HashMap" when I try `HashMap<String,Object>[] params = new HashMap<String,Object>[20000];`

I also failed at attempting to cast an `ArrayList.toArray()` to a `HashMap<String,Object>[]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You really cant. You have to do it like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, Object>[] map = new HashMap[20000];
```

Answer (score 4):

Or with a more barbaric solution you can compile adding:

```
-Xlint:unchecked
```

Comment: +1 for correctly using "barbaric" in a sentence :-)