# Array of lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, object

In Java, how can I create an array where each element is a list of objects containing a pair of keys.

Then given an index of this array, I should be able to search the list at the index provided a single key value and retrieve the corresponding value.

Problem Statement

I have around 2 million webpage name and corresponding to each name are categories (one or more) .

I can hash them down to say 1,00,000 using some hash function but obviously their will be collisions.

I want to build a data structure in Java that can store all this information, and then given a webpage and then, after hashing, given the index, I can find the categories of the web page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java

Comment: like, an `ArrayList<Properties>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is an array of maps:

```
List<Map<KeyType, ValueType>> myList = new ArrayList<Map<KeyType, ValueType>>();
```

This is how you add a map:

```
myList.add(new HashMap<KeyType, ValueType>());
```

This is how you add `value` to the map at index `i` with `key` as key:

```
myList.get(i).put(key, value);
```

To search for `key` in the map at index `i` use:

```
ValueType value = myList.get(i).get(key);
```

**Edit:** After your edit I think that the solution to your problem is to simply use `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. You'd use the name of the `webpage` as key and the list of category-names as values. There is no need to implement your own hash-map (it sounds like that was what you were doing).

Comment: I have an object `webpage` which has `name` and `category` . Each element of the list should be a `webpage` .

Comment: @Rohan: You should use a `HashMap<String, WebPage>` and use `name` as the key. This way you get very fast lookups. If that is not what you want, please take the time and improve your problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Since you added info to your description I'd recommend you to use map of maps. Everything is like @Björn Pollex said but use map instead of list to store webpages themselves.

And one more recommendation. Probably you will want to use `LinkedHashMap` instead of regular HashMap to be able to retrieve the data in the same order that you added it.