# unchecked conversion on multidimensional arraylist

Tags: java

Does anyone know how to fix this warning?

```
MyMain.java:12: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
found   : java.util.ArrayList[][]
required: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>[][]
            obj[count].someArrayList = new ArrayList[4][4];
```

I tried to change this to:

```
obj[count].someArrayList = new ArrayList<String>[4][4];
```

But the amendment changes the warning into the following error:

```
MyMain.java:12: generic array creation
            obj[count].someArrayList = new ArrayList<String>[4][4];
```

The declaration of someArrayList is:

```
public ArrayList<String>[][] someArrayList;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create an array of LinkedLists in Java...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create arrays with generics (hence the error). The warning indicates the heavily discouraged use of raw types with an `ArrayList`.

Instead, the following creates a multidimensional `ArrayList`:

`public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> someArrayList;`

You can then perform normal operations on your multidimensional `ArrayList`.

```
obj[count].someArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> toAdd = new ArrayList<String>();
toAdd.add("test");
toAdd.add("test2");
obj[count].someArrayList.add(toAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way to declare a **multidimensional array** of `ArrayList` is like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<String>[][] someArrayList = new ArrayList[4][4];
someArrayList[0][0] = new ArrayList<String>();
someArrayList[0][1] = new ArrayList<String>();
....
....
```