# Array of LinkedList adding new nodes

Tags: java, linked-list

I've created an array (using the second answer from [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java)) by:

```
public static LinkedList<Connection>[] map;
...  // later ....
map = (LinkedList<Connection>[]) new LinkedList[count];
```

And when I run my program, I get a NullPointerException at the line inside this `for` loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numOfConnections; j++) {
    map[i].add(new Connection(find(s.next()), s.nextDouble(), s.next()));  // NPE!
}
```

Can someone please tell me why this exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `map` is full of `null` when an array is created. You need to initialize each member yourself.

```
// Initialize.
for (int j = 0; j < numOfConnections; j++) {
//                  ^ I assume this means 'count' here.
    map[j] = new LinkedList<Connection>();
}

// Fill
for (int j = 0; j < numOfConnections; j++) {
    map[j].add(new Connection(find(s.next()), s.nextDouble(), s.next()));
//      ^ BTW I think you mean `j` here.
}
```

(Combine the two steps if you like.)