# Cannot create a generic array in Java

Tags: java

I try to create a generic array but I'm taking the error of the title.

```
 ByteConverter<Product> byteconverter = new ByteConverter<Product>();

 //into an inner class I have to declare a final field 
 final ByteConverter<Product>[] byteconverter2 = {byteconverter};
```

So, I searched at the Stackoverflow for a possible solution. I found something similar here: [Cannot create an array of LinkedLists in Java...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java) , so I canged my code to the following:

```
 final ByteConverter<Product>[] byteconverter2 = {(ByteConverter<Product>[])byteconverter};
```

but I still take the same error. I can't understand why..Any help please?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Read through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation. You should find your answer.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: Cannot create a generic array of ByteConverter<Product>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final ByteConverter<Product>[] byteconverter2 = 
   new ByteConverter[]
   {
      byteconverter   
   };
```

this works well

Comment: You don't need to give type on RHS, while initializing array at the time of declaration.

Comment: and it is applicable for java 7 only

Answer (score 1):

This compiles, though with a warning

```
    ByteConverter<Product> byteconverter = new ByteConverter<Product>();
    ByteConverter<Product>[] byteconverter2 = new ByteConverter[] { byteconverter };
```

Read here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html about restrictions for generics