# Create 2D array of Lists in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, pointers, null

I'm trying to create a 2D array of lists for a Sudoku. Essentially 81 lists each containing possible solutions to that box in the Sudoku grid. I've tried multiple declarations so far, but whenever I try to add values to a list it returns a null pointer exception. Here is an example, simply populating each of the lists with the numbers 1-9.

```
List<Integer>[][] sudoku = (List<Integer>[][]) new List[9][9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < 10; ) {
                sudoku[i][j].add(k);
            }
        }
}
```

I'm not even positive a 2D array of lists is the optimal way to go about this, but I've done everything from scratch (with a relatively low knowledge of java) so far so I'd like to follow through with this method. The original code looked as follows:

```
List[][] sudoku = new List[9][9];
```

Research quickly revealed that this wouldn't cut it.

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Comment: Try `List<List<Integer>> sudoku = new List<>();` instead. I think You cannot make an array of collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have create the array of `Lists` but you did not initialize it. Insert this in the second line an the problem should be solved.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
         sudoku[i][j]=new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    }
}
```

Or to do it all in one go do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        sudoku[i][j]= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int k = 1; k < 10; ) {
            sudoku[i][j].add(k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked well as soon as I changed "List<Integer>()" to "ArrayList<Integer>()" seeing as the List isn't considered a concrete class. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Yeah of course! Sorry for the confusion. Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Hakuna Matata, your answer helped me iron out the null pointer and the Sudoku solver worked flawlessly on the first time through :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one. The general idea, create a master list and while you loop through it, create one inner list.

```
    /* Declare your intended size. */
    int mainGridSize = 81;
    int innerGridSize = 9;

    /* Your master grid. */
    List<List<Integer>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(mainGridSize);

    /* Your inner grid */
    List<Integer> innerList = null;

    /* Loop around the mastergrid */
    for (int i=0; i<mainGridSize; i++) {

        /* create one inner grid for each iteration of the main grid */
        innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>(innerGridSize);

        /* populate your inner grid */
        for (int j=0; j<innerGridSize; j++) 
            innerList.add(j);

        /* add it to your main list */
        mainList.add(innerList);
    }
```

Illustrated:

[image]

If you need to vary your grid, just change the values of the gridSize.

Answer (score 2):

[You cannot create array of generic lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217110/1651233).

You can create List of Lists:

```
List<List<List<Integer>>> soduko = new ArrayList<>();
```

And then populate it as you wish.

or use casting:

```
List[][] soduko = (List<IntegerNode>[][]) new LinkedList[9][9];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you need exactly 81 2D arrays, you can create 3D array:

```
int[][][] sudoku = new int[81][9][9];
```

The way you did it now would produce compilation error.