# Java LinkedList Array referencing

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, adt

So I have a simple program that creates a `LinkedList` array of given size n, with each value in the list representing a new separate `LinkedList` data Structure.

```
public class Graph {

public final LinkedList[] graph;

public Graph(int n){
    graph = new LinkedList[n];  

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        graph[i] = new LinkedList();
    }

}

public void addEdge(int x, int y){

    graph[x].addFirst(y);
    graph[y].addFirst(x);

}
```

For some reason, however, when I call the `addEdge()` method with two int values, instead of adding them to the specific called `LinkedList` in `graph[]`, it adds them to every `LinkedList` in `graph[]`.

What is the problem here?

Edit:*

```
public void addEdge(int x, int y){

    graph[x].addFirst(y);
    graph[y].addFirst(x);

    for (int i=0; i<graph.length; i++){
        Node tmp = graph[i].first;

        System.out.println(i + ":");

        while (tmp != null){
            System.out.print(tmp.name + " ");

            tmp = tmp.Rnext;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

}


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Graph myGraph1 = new Graph(8);
    myGraph1.addEdge(1, 2);
    myGraph1.addEdge(1, 7);
    myGraph1.addEdge(1, 4);
    myGraph1.addEdge(2, 5);
    myGraph1.addEdge(2, 6);
    myGraph1.addEdge(6, 3);
    myGraph1.addEdge(3, 8);
    myGraph1.addEdge(5, 7); 
    }
}

Here is the output of graph:
0:
1 2 
1:
1 2 
2:
1 2 
3:
1 2 
4:
1 2 
5:
1 2 
6:
1 2 
7:
1 2 

0:
1 7 1 2 
1:
1 7 1 2 
2:
1 7 1 2 
3:
1 7 1 2 
4:
1 7 1 2 
5:
1 7 1 2 
6:
1 7 1 2 
7:
1 7 1 2 

0:
1 4 1 7 1 2 
1:
1 4 1 7 1 2 
2:
1 4 1 7 1 2 
3:
1 4 1 7 1 2 
4:
1 4 1 7 1 2 
5:
1 4 1 7 1 2 
6:
1 4 1 7 1 2 
7:
1 4 1 7 1 2 

0:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
1:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
2:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
3:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
4:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
5:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2   
6:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
7:
2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 

0:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
1:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
2:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
3:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
4:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
5:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
6:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
7:
2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 

0:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
1:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
2:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
3:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
4:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
5:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
6:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2 
7:
6 3 2 6 2 5 1 4 1 7 1 2
```

Here is the LinkedList and Node Class I am using:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList {

public static Node first;

    public LinkedList(){ 
    first = null;

    } 

    // Returns true if the list is empty 
    public boolean isEmpty(){ 
    return first == null; 
    } 

    // Inserts a new node at the beginning of this list. 
    public void addFirst(int name){ 

    first = new Node(name, first);
    }


    public boolean findData(int d){
    if(first == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Node tmp = first;

    while (tmp != null) {

        if (tmp.name == d) return true;
        tmp = tmp.Rnext;
    } return false;
}
}


    public class Node { 

    public int name;
    public Node Rnext;

    public Node(){ 
    name = 0;
    Rnext = null; 
    } 

    public Node(int n, Node r){ 
    this.name = n;
    this.Rnext = r;
} 

}
```

Comment: How are you checking that they are actually being added to every linked list?

Comment: See here for syntax of creating lists of lists in Java, that seems like it could be the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java

Comment: Does it only happen when `x == y`?

Comment: Can you show the code that creates the instance and adds edge? Also add some sysout for debugging purpose and paste the output here.

Comment: I am printing each linked list at the end of the program, but this code adds values to every linkedlist in the array, opposed to just the reference of graph[x] and graph[y]

Comment: Good, can you show us the code that adds and prints, along with what you see on console as output?

Comment: You're not using `java.util.LinkedList`, are you?  What `LinkedList` class are you using?  If it's custom, can you show us that code?

Comment: `public static Node first;` there's your problem right there

Comment: Indeed, first is static, which means all LinkedList objects share the same contents. Why not use java.util.LinkedList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Node first;
```

This is the problem.  Every single `LinkedList` you make is sharing the same `Node`, so they're all effectively the same list.

Don't use `static` for instance variables.