# How do I create an array of a generic type? (for use with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate)

Tags: java, arrays, spring, dictionary, jdbc

[NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) in Spring has a method called [batchUpdate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.Map:A-) which accepts a `Map<String, ?>[]` array as a parameter. How do I construct one of those?

Here are some examples of what I've tried doing:

```
Map<String, Object>[] rows = new Map<String, Object>[] { };

Map<String, Object>[] rows = new HashMap<String, Object>[] { };

List<Map<String, Object>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object>[] rows = rowList.toArray();
```

None of those work. How do I do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that none of these work?

Comment: @KevinWorkman - as in, that code will not compile. I get build errors.

Comment: @azurefrog - I'm looking at the "possible duplicate" you posted but I honestly don't see a solution to my problem there.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java

Comment: They are talking about within a generic method, but if you just replace the generic type with the concrete one you're trying to create it'll work.  e.g. `Map<String, Object>[] rows = (Map<String, Object>[]) Array.newInstance(Map.class, arraySize);` compiles just fine.

Comment: @SoaperGEM If it's not compiling could you please post your build errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8052827/2158288