# exception while creating arrays of Arraylist

Tags: java

I have java program like this

```
public class Distribution {

    private LinkedList<Integer > group[];    

    public Distribution() {
        group[0] = new LinkedList<>();
        group[0].add(1);
        group[0].add(2);
        group[0].add(3);

        group[1] = new LinkedList<>();
        group[1].add(4);
        group[1].add(5);
        group[1].add(6);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Distribution distribution = new Distribution();
    }
}
```

but the compiler says
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: I guess it's not the compiler complaining about NPE but rather the JRE

Comment: That's not an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized your array. Use the following code to remove the NullPointerException:

```
private LinkedList<Integer> group[] = new LinkedList[10];
```

(where you have to replace 10 by the size you need).

Note that generics and arrays are not really convenient to use together. In particular, the above code gives a compiler warning (because it uses a raw type), and

```
private LinkedList<Integer> group[] = new LinkedList<Integer>[2];
```

doesn't compile.

In general, using an array of a generic class is not a good idea. Consider using an `ArrayList` instead of an array:

```
public class Distribution {
    private ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> group = new ArrayList<>();    

    public Distribution() {
        group.add(new LinkedList<>());
        group.get(0).add(1);
        ...
        group.add(new LinkedList<>());
        group.get(1).add(4);
        ...
    }
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You never initialized your `group[]`.

```
private LinkedList<Integer> group[] = new LinkedList[2]; //example
```

You must initialize the array specify the length...

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
private LinkedList<Integer> group[] = new LinkedList[10];
```

However it will generate a compiler warning.

You cannot/should not create arrays of lists in java

Use Lists of Lists instead of Arrays of Lists

```
List< List<IntegerNode>> nodeLists = new LinkedList< List< IntegerNode >>();
```

See Answers to question - [Cannot create an array of LinkedLists in Java...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java)