# Generic array creation error with LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>[]

Tags: java, android

I've declared a variable as:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>[] function_labels;
```

but when I try and instantiate it with:

```
function_labels = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>[2];
```

I get a 'generic array creation' error.

I've searched on here, and although there are many posts about this error message,
no-one seems to have offered a solution which actually works, so I'm trying again...

I don't mind what type of collection `function_labels` is, as long as it works and I can access indexed members of it later. A simple array seems the 'lightest' solution, but there may be others which will work.

Thanks

Comment: tldr: `LinkedHashMap<X,Y>[]` is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to cast type to declare like this [Generic Array Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217065/cannot-create-an-array-of-linkedlists-in-java)

```
function_labels = ( LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>[]) new LinkedHashMap<?,?>[2];
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Wouldn't have guessed that answer in decades!!!